# What need to be done to implement "import ... as ..." in java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, syntax

If this is possible, what part of java compiler need to be re-engineered to has an "import as" statement, so codes can look like this way:

```
import java.util.Date;
import mypackage.Date as MyDate;
//...
javaDate = new Date();
myDate = new MyDate();
```

Even more, what need to get this kind of syntax:

```
import java.util.Date;
import path.to.mypackage as MP;
//...
javaDate2 = new Date();
myDate2 = new MP.Date();
```

And what trouble it will cause for existing codes?

Comment: Are you implying that you intend to "re-engineer" the Java compiler?

Comment: Just try to understand *java* way.

Comment: Note: The entire `import` mechanism exists only at compile-time. Once you arrive at `.class` files it's all fully-quallified class names. So that change would *only* require changes to the compiler, no other part of the system (JVM, libraries, ...) would need to be changed.

Comment: This feature has been there in scala forever, I hoped I would have been introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This obviously requires changes to the Java compiler. If you're really interested in doing something like this, then look at the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) project, where you will find the source code for Oracle's Java compiler and runtime environment.

If you want to propose this as a new feature for a future version of Java, then you'd have to go through the [Java Community Process](http://jcp.org/).

Comment: I vote this post as the best and simple answer. Though, I don't understand usage of this feature if this mechanism propose to JCP. It is easier and readable to Everyone to write `Date` instead of `MyDate`

Comment: In guessing, there must be a lot of JCPs exist for this kind of *syntax sugar*.

Comment: @wahyu.fahmy There are examples of where this could be useful. There's for example `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. If you import them both, then Java doesn't know which one you mean if you use use the name `Date`. It would be useful if you could rename it to `SqlDate`, for example.

Comment: Yes wahyu.fahmy, @Jesper point the direction to the answer, and it's right. And he also kindly point out the question could has it own usefullness.