# Eclipse, completion of inner classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got a class `B` defined as inner class for `A`

```
package hello;

class A {
    static class B {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'm editing a third class `C`, and I need to declare a `A.B` object:

```
A.B something = new A.B(...);
```

If I use Eclipse's code completion, and I let Eclipse infer the type of the expression, I get something like this:

```
import hello.A;
import hello.A.B;
// ...
class C {
    // ...
    void foo() {
        B something = new A.B(...);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this behavior and have eclipse using `A.B` instead of importing it?

What I would like is this:

```
import hello.A;

class C {
    void foo() {
        A.B something = new A.B(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you mean that A is actually some.package.A; and you want to use the fully qualified name within your source code? If so, I am sure that eclipse can be configured somewhere to do that; but probably it will then do that for all classes. You see, eclipse is trying to create syntactically correct java source code; and I don't see how you would want to use A and A.B without importing those class names upfront.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
package my.pack;

public class A {

  public static class B {}
}
```

and then

```
package my.other.pack;

public class C {

  my.pack.A.B myB = new my.pack.A.B();

}
```

but keep an eye on Eclipse, I think it will try to optimize your imports (I think you can disable it, but I don't know how).

Comment: I guess you misunderstood the question. OP doesn't want an import for class `B`. He wants to use the outer class name instead: `A.B`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also angry about that: I write in comment

```
see Outerclass.In
```

press autocompletion, and then eclipse removes the "Outerclass.", completes the inner class, make the link well

```
... see {@link Innerclass}
```

and adds automatically an import

```
import package.path.OuterClass.Innerclass;
```

That is against well code styles, as also many other people has written! I have to do the work, remove the dirty import, write again the "Outerclass." manually without code completion. It is stupid, a helper will help me stupidly and I have do the work to remove. I have searched for a solution in eclipse and found https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=305205 with last entry in 2018, nothing is done.

There may be a help:
Preferences - Java - Editor - Content Assist: Uncheck the check box "Add import instead of qualified names". But I guess, now, also on the autocompleted classes the import is not written automatically. But this may be a lesser disadvantage. The import is fast written manually by copying the "packge.path", to to top, write "import " and paste. In the moment for me: get experience with.